# iOS: How to fill a rectangle except in one area?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I've used the CGContext based routine to fill a rectangle, but this time I actually want to fill all of a rectangle EXCEPT one part of it. I know this is possible in other drawing systems for other platofrm but can it be done with core graphics on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Both `borderWidth` and `cornerRadius` are animatable properties. So you could just animate them directly (using CABasicAnimation). In that rendering, you'd go from no border and no corners to having a border and corners in an animated way.

[image]

If you want to animate the rectangular tracing of the border, you'd need to use a CAShapeLayer (because the end of its path is animatable) and provide the illusion that way.